# Enum static or non-static method

Tags: java, static, enums

Consider the following enum class

```
public enum ClassA {
    CHECK1("X", 0),
    CHECK2("Y", 2),
    CHECK3("Z", 1);

    private final String id;
    private final String cdValue;

    private ClsA(String id, String cdValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cdValue = cdValue;
    }

    private String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private String getCdValue() {
        return cdValue ;
    }

    private static final List<String> cdValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        for (ClassA clsA : ClassA.values()) {   
            cdValues.add(clsA.getCdValue());    
        }
    }   

    public boolean isCdValue(String cdValue)
    {
        if clsValues.contains(cdValue)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }   
}
```

The question that I have is does the method `isCdValue` has to be static. I have to use this method `isCdValue` for every input given by the client. Therefore the method parameter `cdValue` changes for every input.

If it cannot be static then I would like to know how I can access this method. Please note I am primarily interested in learning about static of non-static method call. If it is a non-static call in a enum then how can we call this non static method. I am not trying to resolve the issue of how to get about checking the `cdValue` exists or not. It is just an example.

Answer (score 12):

> does the method isCdValue has to be static.

Yes, the method isCdValue has to be static here.
An enum is a special kind of class. An enum constant defines an instance of the enum type. An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. Hence `new` can not be used to instantiate an enum.

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum
>   constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly
>   instantiate an enum type (§15.9.1).

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Answer (score 5):

If you have to put the checking method in the Enum, I think it should be static

you can do this check:

```
ClassA.isCdValue(para)
```

Note that, you cannot `new` an Enum object. So if the method in your Enum, and it is not static, you cannot call it unless you have an Instance. but the goal of your method is checking if the string could be an instance.

another possibility is, use an immutable collection in your Enumm, and make it `static` and `public`. Then you could just call `ClassA.CD_VALUES.contains(para)`

Comment: I am learning java so I am confused about static and non static. Let us assume the user gave input of cdValue = 2. I am using the method isCdValue in the enum ClsA to find out if this cdValue exists.  The next user gave input of cdValue =8. Again I am using the same method isCdValue to check if it exists. In the first case it will return true and the second case it returns false. Does the method isCdValue have to be static or non-static.

Comment: @nonenone as I answered above, if the method is in the Enum class, it should be static. otherwise you cannot call it. You don't have an instance of the ClassA.

Comment: Sorry to ask the same question..what I am worried about is will the users get the correct result using the static method isCdValue in enum. In the above case, the first user should get true as result and the second user as false. Static I always associate with class level but the search input parameter cdValue depends on the instance of the user. Therefore to put in another way, if I ran consecutively

Comment: @nonenone I don't see any problem with that `static` method. If it broke your program somewhere, please give some concrete example. then we can see where is the problem.

Comment: sorry to ask the same question..Static I always associate with class level but the search input parameter cdValue depends on the instance of the user. Therefore if I have public classB{  public String doProcess(String inputCdValue

Comment: sorry to ask the same question..Static I always associate with class level but the search input parameter cdValue depends on the instance of the user. Therefore if I have public classB{ public String doProcess(String inputCdValue) {boolean verifiedCdValue = ClassA.isCdValue(inputCdValue); }}}. Let us assume for various instances of classB the method doProcess is called with inputCdValue =1, inputCdValue=10, inputCdValue=3 etc. Will the verifiedCdValue be true for instance1, false for instance2 and true for instance3 or will the verifiedCdValue be impacted by other instances

Comment: @nonenone I am not sure what has confused you. A static method is associating to a class. but it is not problem for a static method to process parameter from other classes. If you read some static methods from jre itself, or take a look some util classes, you will see. also do some test with your thought, the result will tell you if that way works or not. then you learned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access it from `ClsA`, you will have to make it static, if you want to access it from an *instance* of `ClsSa` then it doesn't.

A couple of other things: where do you declare clsValues in the first place?

There's no need for the complex if, you may replace this:

```
public boolean isCdValue(String cdValue)
    {
        if clsValues.contains(cdValue)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

with this

```
public boolean isCdValue(String cdValue){
    return clsValues.contains(cdValue)
}
```

Last little thing, I'd strongly suggest you put curly braces around all your `if` and `else`'s clauses, I've spent many a debugging hour because someone added a second line under the else, fooled by the indent and thinking it would only execute on the else.

Comment: That’s true, I’m always surprised how often I see things like this obsolete `if` statement. The “advanced” programmers write something like `return condition? true: false;` ;^)

Comment: @Miquel, I don't think this is appropriate, OP will need to get values of enum and iterate values to get match! More appropriate is declare static method, iterate all values of enum and match with enum values.

Comment: @Holger why does "advanced" need the "true" and "false"? why not `return condition;`?

Comment: @Imagination: that’s why I put that word into quotes. I did not write advanced but “advanced”. But I still see that code pattern too often in real life code— even in the JRE implementation itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, you do not need `static List` but the method has to be static as answered by Kent,

```
public static ClassA getClassAByCDValue(String cdValue)
{
    for(ClassA value: ClassA.values())
    {
        if(value.cdValue.contains(cdValue))
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static boolean isCDValue(String cdValue)
{
    for(ClassA value: ClassA.values())
    {
        if(value.cdValue.contains(cdValue))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using above will be more appropriate as you just have to take care with adding/removing items in enum.